# Compare a New Array Entry to all its Ancestors

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, while-loop

I'm attempting to create an array composed of unique random integers. The method I've constructed, shown below, will almost work. The problem is in the while loop, that compares the new random entry to its immediate ancestor. This condition ensures that there will not be a pair of matching values, side-by-side, in the array. Unfortunately this condition does not compare the new random value to every random value generated thus far. How can I accomplish this?

```
private static Random rand = new Random();

//'dynamicLength' is dependent on another object. With the way I've set up the 
//method, the size shouldn't matter.
private static int[] randArr = new int[dynamicLength];

public static int[] randGenArr(int upBound, int lowBound)
{
    int newRand;

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < randArr.length; i1++)
    {
       //new random value
       newRand = rand.nextInt(upBound - lowBound + 1) + lowBound;

       //walk through the randArr up to the point we initialized
       //last iteration
       for (int i2 = 0; i2 <= i1; i2++)
       {
           //compare the new value to its IMMEDIATE ancestor
           while (newRand == randArr[i2])
           {
               newRand = rand.nextInt(upBound - lowBound + 1) + lowBound;
           }
       } 
       //after validation, initialize randArr          
       randArr[i1] = newRand;
   }

   return randArr;
}
```

I'm only focused on the body of this code. I've included the method header and the
field declarations for clarity.

Comment: How many values are you going to consider between `upBound` and `lowBound`?  If you expect to use all of them or nearly so, you could just put them all in an list and `shuffle` the list, then there will be no repeats but they'll be in random order.

Comment: @EricRenouf I've tried shuffle to no result, could you reply with a clear response. Perhaps I missused shuffle. Oh, and at most I'll sample 30% of my range.

Comment: wouldn't an easy solution be a for:each loop to compare the new number to all current numbers, or does for:each not work on arrays?

Comment: @MeikVtune I'm not sure, but I think you're talking about an enhanced for loop. Jean Logeart, see below, and I had a conversation about this, and we concluded that the value 0 would never be able to be generated this way. Since the array is initialized with all zeros by default, the enhanced for loop will read zeros, and will never allow the rand value to be a 0.

Comment: I'm gonna form an answer and remove it if I'm wrong, it would be nice to know.

Answer (score 3):

Set is a good tool for keeping track of unique items. You could use set to generate random numbers and only in the end return array.

```
Integer[] randNumbers(int amount, int lower, int upper) {
    Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>();
    while(result.size() < amount) {             //try until there are enough numbers in result
         result.add( /*generate new number*/);  //add only unique number to result
    }
    return result.toArray(new Integer[amount]); //converts Set to array
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Could you point me to some materials to learn about `Set`? Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @CraigK.Take a look at the Javadocs for Hashset: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

Comment: Set contains only unique items. `result.add()` will add new number only if `result` does not contain it yet. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

Comment: @NazariiBardiuk Thank you for the reference Nazarii. After reading the first line **"A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements"** I can tell that this is a promising lead.

Answer (score 1):

The `Set` answer from Nazarii is almost certainly going to be the one you want, but for completeness from my initial suggestion you could do the following:

```
public static int[] randGenArr(int upBound, int lowBound) {
    // First we'll put all our possible values into a List
    List<Integer> vals = new ArrayList(upBound - lowBound + 1);
    for(int i = lowBound; i < upBound; i++) {
        vals.add(i);
    }

    // Now put that list into a random order
    Collections.shuffle(vals);

    // now grab the first X we want and put them into the array we're setting, or if we could return a List<Integer> we could create a SubList
    for(int i = 0; i < ranArr.length; i++) {
        ranArr[i] = vals.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now that's interesting. So you took all possible values that could be generated, populated an ArrayList with these values, shuffled the list, then sequentially took the amount of values you wanted to populate `randArr`. Do I have that right?

Comment: @CraigK. Exactly right, but if you don't want most of the space this is probably not as good of an approach as using a `Set`

Comment: Yes, `Set` does look promising, but this is a simplistic solution that I can get my head around _now_. I could troubleshoot this more easily than `Set`, which I'm not familiar with. I do look forward to learning `Set` though.

Answer (score 0):

In your outer for loop:

```
// generate a number and check if it is already contained in the array
newRand = rand.nextInt(upBound - lowBound + 1) + lowBound;
boolean contained = isContained(newRand, randArr, i1);

// if it is contained, repeat
while(contained) {
    newRand = rand.nextInt(upBound - lowBound + 1) + lowBound;
    contained = isContained(newRand, randArr, i1);
}

randArr[i1] = newRand;
```

And the `isContained` function:

```
private static boolean isContained(int e, int[] array, int upTo) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < upTo ; i++) {
        if(array[i] == e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so `isContained` is a boolean method that walks through `randArr` as it stands. Just one question, since `isContained` walks through the entire array, much of which will have the default initialization of 0 each walk-through, is it a true assumption that 0 can never be generated and stored?

Comment: I added an ``upTo`` argument to look up to this index

Comment: Very cool, but I think the for statement needs to read `i <= upTo`. Otherwise, the loop won't check the immediate ancestor. At least, that's my interpretation. Is that correct?

Comment: No, it should be ``<``. Think about the first iteration where ``upTo`` is ``0``.

Comment: But `upTo` is for the programmer to enter right? So if the programmer does put in 0, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a way to check for dublicate entries without using a Set(minor think-errors may be present)

```
for(int a : randArr){
if(newRand == a){
    newRand = rand.nextInt(upBound - lowBound + 1) + lowBound;
}
}
```

With this you check all current numbers (to be precise you check until the end of `randArr`), if a dublicate is found you roll a new random number.

The thing you now have to do is implement this into your current program, as I don't know how to make sure that the new random number isn't in the Array.

Comment: In Line 5 of my code where `randArr` is initialized, every value in that array is initialized as zero. `lowBound` is 0 and my circumstance. So when the enhanced for loop walks through the entire `randArr` array, it will see a zero in almost every comparison and not allow `randArr` to possibly be initialized with a zero until the end of the array (when the last 0 is overwritten). Of course, this method could work if `lowBound` is any positive value not equal to 0.

Comment: Also, don't remove your answer even if it's wrong in my case. Like I said, it can work if **`lowBound` is any positive value not equal to 0**.

Comment: @CraigK. it doesn't matter if you initalize it with 0's. You said that you can't generate random 0's which means that the if never happens for the not yet randomized numbers, it'd just be a way to always check all elements for possible dublicates.